# What is the preferred method for sharing compiled C code in an R package and running it from another?

Tags: c, r, package

Assume I have two packages in R, the first named `foo`, the second named `bar`. I want to include a C function in `foo` and share that functionality with `bar` in a way that is platform independent and consistent with the CRAN policies.

What is the preferred method of doing this, and how should I go about using function registration and dynamic libraries?

The purpose of my question is that, even though I read through all the documentation I could find, there is nothing that occured to me as the obvious thing to do, and I am unsure what the most sustainable course of action is.

**Example:**

Assume that in one package `foo`, I define a C function `addinc` which adds two numbers.

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP addinc(SEXP x_, SEXP y_) {
  double x = asReal(x_);
  double y = asReal(y_);

  double sum = x + y;

  return ScalarReal(sum);
}
```

In the same package, I can try calling `addinc` in an R function named `addinr` via the `.Call` interface.

```
addinr <- function(x,y){
  .Call("addinc", x, y, PACKAGE="foo")
}
```

However, when building, checking and installing the package, running `addinr` returns the error below, presumably because the function is not yet registered within R.

```
library(foo)
addinr(1,2)
```

> Error in .Call("addinc", x, y, PACKAGE = "foo") :
>    "addinc" not available for .Call() for package "foo"

As it seems to me, the easiest way to solve this is to build a dynamic library for the compiled code by adding `useDynLib(foo)` to `foo`s NAMESPACE file.
This appears to solve the problem because I can now call `addinr()` without problems. Moreover, I can run `.Call("addinc", ..., PACKAGE="foo")` directly from within R.

My *real* question, however, occurs when a second package, say `bar`, is supposed to use `foo`s `addinc`. For example, assume that `bar` defines a function `multiplyinr` as follows.

```
multiplyinr <- function(x,y){
  ans <- 0
  for(i in 1:y) ans <- .Call("addinc", ans, x, PACKAGE="foo")
  ans
}
```

This, in fact, works completely fine, and I can call `multiplyinr` within R. However, when building and checking `bar`, I receive a Note complaining about the fact that `bar` is calling foreign language functions from a different package.

> Foreign function call to a different package:
>     .Call("addinc", ..., PACKAGE = "foo")
>   See chapter ‘System and foreign language interfaces’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150185/foreign-function-calls-to-a-different-package-note), the package `bar` would not be suitable for submission to CRAN because using `.Call()` in this way is not considered "portable" as explained in the [Writing R Extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Writing-portable-packages).

In conclusion, the simple solution of having `foo` include a `useDynLib(foo)` in its NAMESPACE file does not quite seem to cut it. Therefore my question: What is the preferred method to share a C function with other packages?

**Moreover:**

Is using `useDynLib()` truly dangerous or inconsistent with the CRAN policies? What is the purpose of declaring `useDynLib()` in the NAMESPACE file as an alternative to registering and building the shared library manually?

Would manually registering the C function and bulding the shared library change anything (i.e., using `R_RegisterCCallable()` or `R_registerRoutines()`)?

Comment: Have you seen this section of R-ext? https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Linking-to-native-routines-in-other-packages

Comment: As I understood it, using `R_RegisterCCallable` is mostly intended for linking at the C level. However, I only want to access C code at the R level (using `.Call`). This is also why I asked if registering the functions in that way would offer any improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general idea is that the 'native symbol info' objects created by using e.g. `useDynLib(<pkg>, <symbol>)` are not part of the public API of a package, and so client packages should not be calling them directly (it's assumed they could be changed in future revisions of the package).

There are two ways to 'export' a compiled routine for use by client packages:

1. Just export an R wrapper function in `foo` that calls the native routine directly, or
2. Use the `R_RegisterCCallable()` / `R_GetCCallable()` pair of functions to get a pointer to the function you want. (Package `foo` would call `R_RegisterCCallable()` to make some function available; client package `bar` would call `R_GetCCallable()` to get a pointer to that function)

In other words, if a package author 'registers' their C functions, they're declaring that to be part of the public C API of their package, and allow client packages to use / call that through this interface.

Comment: Dear @KevinUshey, may I ask you if it is possible (and how) to use in a second package `bar` C functions from a first package `foo` if they were registered by means of `R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL)` and `useDynLib(foo, .registration = TRUE)`? Thanks!